# res.data.forEach is not a function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, axios

I have got an error: Uncaught TypeError: res.data.forEach is not a function

when I use forEach with axios.get. How can I resolve problem?

script:

```
let totalData = [];
let monthData = [];

$(async function () {
  await axios.get(`/dashboard/chart/month`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);

      res.data.forEach((data) => {
        totalData.push(data.total);
        monthData.push(data.months);
      });

    });

});
```

Data:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "months": "January 21",
            "total": 0
        },
        {
            "months": "February 21",
            "total": 0
        },
        {
            "months": "March 21",
            "total": 0
        },
        {
            "months": "April 21",
            "total": 0
        }
    ],
    "msg": null
}
```

Comment: Why are you using async and updating the axios one? If you're using jQuery, can you try using async jQuery's AJAX call in sync mode?

Comment: Your `res.data` seems to be an `Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just realised. Look at your `res.data` and you need `res.data.data`. Replace your code with:

```js
let totalData = [];
let monthData = [];

$(async function () {
  await axios.get(`/dashboard/chart/month`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);

      // Add another data here:
      res.data.data.forEach((data) => {
        totalData.push(data.total);
        monthData.push(data.months);
      });

    });

});
```

The `res.data` is the Axios's version. It has your data + status and other stuff. You have your `data` as well. So you need `res.data.data`.